# Making gradient border look like a line

Tags: css, gradient, linear-gradients

How can I make the gradient border between to colors look like a line? Is there also a way to start the line in left bottom corner and not in the middle of right side of the button? I'm using this css for this:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #00C9FF 30%, black 50%)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/746/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move both colors to the same position:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #00C9FF 30%, black 30%);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to get the expected result:

```css
div {
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #00C9FF calc(50% - 1px), black calc(50% + 1px));
  border:7px solid #00C9FF;
  color:#fff;
  height:100px;
  line-height:100px;
  text-align:center;
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<div>Test</div>
```

The [`calc()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc-notation) is needed to make the line smooth. Otherwise the border looks very strange on some browser.